# Print elsewhere than stdout and stderr

Tags: python, printing

Currently, I can print information to stdout and also to stderr, but I would like to print information about progress and print it to stdout, stderr and somewhere else. Is this possible?

Comment: Where do you want to print it?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to *simulataneously* print output to `stdout`, `stderr`, and *somewhere else*?

Comment: Yes to stdout, stderr and somewhere else - to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output to the console comes only via stdout and stderr as far as I know.

Do you want to print to a file, then you can do this

```
  with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:
       f.write('this is a test')
```

or alternatively if you prefer using `print`:

```
       print >> f, 'this is a test'
```

In the above example a file named `outfile.txt` is opened for `w`rite access. This means any data already present will be wiped out by new data written to it. If you wanted to append you'd open the file in `a` mode. See the [documentation for open()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) for more information.

Files that are opened need to be closed, using the `with` construct takes care of that for you (and also closes the file in case you encounter an exception).

Comment: Cause I wanna print progress information - it should be print to the term.

Comment: @Andrew Output to the console comes only via stdout and stderr as far as I know. If not, then I'll be happy to learn something new.

Comment: printing directly to `/dev/console` on a unix-like machine will probably work, although it's not necessarily a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial) module to log information simultaneously to different places:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('your_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('errors.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

logger.warning('I am a warning')
logger.error('I will be printed, but written to the log file as well')
logger.info('I am an info message')
```

Comment: I am not that familiar with the logging module, isn't the output to the console (if there is any) delivered via `stderr` or `stdout`? (I need to read up on that module)

Comment: when I redirect stderr to the file, that redirect logger messages too

Comment: @Levon: I think that depends on the severity of the message.

Comment: @Andrew: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Blender I guess my question is geared towards OP wanting to display messages to the console in addition to using stderr and stdout .. I don't think that's possible (ie stdout and stderr will always be involved for display to the console). OP can display simultaneously to a number of "places" (incl files), but only stderr/stdout go to term unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score -1):

Make a class with method named write(), then you can use

```
print 'text' >> Printer()
```

to print 'text' to the Printer() object (python 2.x) or

```
print('text', file=Printer())
```

in python 3.x

Comment: any string you'd like to print, just replace 'text' with it

Comment: @pythonm: I would suggest subclassing `StringIO` (which already has a write method).